# xamarin.forms find out what picture is set to imagesource

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a picture and I need to find out what picture is set to it:

I tried:

```
 if (img_adPic1.Source == ImageSource.FromFile("img_camera"))
{...}
```

But that never returns true, even when it states on the imagesource, that under file it is listed as "img_camera".

How do I find out what picture is set to imagesource?

Than you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `FileImageSource` to compare.

```
 var s =  img_adPic1.Source as FileImageSource;
       
        if (s.File == "pink.jpg")//filename with extension
        {

        }
```

Comment: Thank you, that did work. Only, that it is WITHOUT EXTENSION! But that might be, because I am doing this from xaml without the extension. Anyway, thank you!